# Updated grub 2 config when win10 is updating, cannot continue update now, how to fix it?

Tags: windows, fedora, grub2

I have win10 and fedora 27 on two different hard disks, and I use grub 2 as bootloader. Today win10 autorestart to update, and my default boot system is fedora, so I enter fedora to change grub 2 boot order and `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg`, then I cannot enter win10. Black screen and only a cursor at upside left corner if I choose to boot in `windows boot manager`.

Now win10 is still under a updating state, so I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue too, in short it is solved this way:

1. boot from windows installation disk
2. go to repair
3. use console method
4. use the Bootrec.exe tool to repair the original windows loader
   by this time you will not be able to boot to ubuntu from the hdd
5. boot windows
6. update works in with the original loader installed
7. boot ubuntu live usb
8. restore grub